# Cannot find my test_helper file (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My test fails when trying to find the test_helper file.

My file:

```
    require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'
    require 'admin/supplier_controller'

    #Re-raise errors caugth by the controller 
    class Admin::SupplierController; def rescue_action(e) raise e end; end

    class Admin::SupplierControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase 
      fixtures :suppliers

      def setup
        @controller = Admin::SupplierController.new
        @request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
        @response = ActionController::TestResponse.new
      end

      def test_new
        get :new
        assert_template 'admin/supplier/new'
        assert_tag 'h1', :content => 'Create new supplier'
        assert_tag 'form', :attributes => {:action => '/admin/supplier/create'}
      end 
    end
```

Comment: Could it be that `test_helper.rb` is _not_ one folder above the file you are trying to run?

Comment: Where is `test_helper` located and where are you accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

No need to do this:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'
```

Just `require 'test_helper'` on the top of the test file, and add `-Itest` option to run the test. (assuming test_helper.rb is located in test/ directory)